# How to avoid parent pom from maven dependency?

Tags: java, jar, build, maven-3, pom.xml

My project "XYZ" needs a dependency jar , say "A.jar".

This A.jar is having a parent pom "B.pom" (not jar), but this parent pom file is not present in repository as it is not uploaded during the release of A.jar.

Now, when I build XYZ, it tries to download the parent "B.pom" as well along with the dependency "A.jar". And it fails. 
Is there any way to exclude parent pom of my dependency "A.jar" ? Am using Maven 3.

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 0):

You can define all plugins in parent pom in pluginManagement section

```
<pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                ...
                 <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <includeTypes>tar.bz2</includeTypes>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/dependencies</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
              ...
            </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

And after in parent and child poms you can control the execution phase of this plugin.If you paste this in parent pom do not forget option `<inherited>false</inherited>`, its disable execution inheritance in child pom.

```
<plugins>
      <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
  </plugins>
```